# (VUE.js) The event doesn't work when called outside the component

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm making a small page for the product based on [this tutorial](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/intro-to-vue-js/communicating-events). On the page I have a `product` component, where I keep a "add to cart" button. The card itself, however, is separated from the component and located inside `index.html`, that's why my `cart` property is being kept inside `vue app` (where app is an id of my root div in index.html).

**Problem:** I need my "add to cart" button to increment the number in the cart itself. I can't really understand how can I do this using `addToCart` and `updateCart` methods, as shown in the tutorial.

Can anyone help me out with this issue? I will appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

```js
Vue.component('product', {
    props: {
      premium: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
      }
    },
    template: `
    <div id="product">
    
      <div class="product-image">
      <img :src="image" />      
      </div>
      
      <div class="product-info">
      
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <p>Shipping: {{ shipping }}</p>
        
        <p v-if="inStock">In Stock</p>
        <p v-else>Out of Stock</p>
        
        <h2>Details</h2>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="detail in details">{{ detail }}</li>
        </ul>

        <h3>Colors:</h3>
        <div v-for="(variant,index) in variants" :key="variant.variantId">
          <div class="color-box" :style="{ backgroundColor: variant.variantColor }" @mouseover="updateProduct(index)"></div>
        </div>

        <button :class="{ disabledButton: !inStock }" v-on:click="add-to-cart" :disabled="!inStock">Add to Cart</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    `,
    data() {
      return {
        product: "Socks",
        brand: "Vue Mastery",
        selectedVariant: 0,
        details: ["80% cotton", "20% polyester", "Gender-neutral"],
        variants: [
            {
              variantId: 2234,
              variantQuantity: 15,
              variantColor: "green",
              variantImage: "./assets/vmSocks-green.jpg"     
            },
            {
              variantId: 2235,
              variantQuantity: 0,
              variantColor: "blue",
              variantImage: "./assets/vmSocks-blue.jpg"
            }
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addToCart() {
        this.$emit('add-to-cart')
      },
      updateProduct(index) {
        this.selectedVariant = index
      }
    },
    computed: {
      title() {
        return this.brand + ' ' + this.product
      },
      image() {
        return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantImage
      },
      inStock() {
        if (this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantQuantity > 0) {
          return true
        } else {
          return false
        }
      },
      shipping() {
        if (this.premium) {
          return "Free"
        } else {
          return 2.99
        }
      }
    }
  })
  
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      premium: true,
      cart: 0
    },
    methods: {
        updateCart() {
          this.cart += 1
        }
    }
  })
```

```css
body {
  font-family: tahoma;
  color:#282828;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav-bar {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #84CF6A, #16C0B0);
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  padding: 1rem;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px .5px 1px #d8d8d8;
}

.product-image {
  width: 80%;
}

.product-image,
.product-info {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.color-box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cart {
  margin-right: 25px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #1E95EA;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
} 

.disabledButton {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
}

.review-form {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

input {
  width: 100%;  
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.tab {
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.activeTab {
  color: #16C0B0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Vue app</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav-bar"></div>

        <div id="app">
            <div class="cart">
                <p>Cart({{ cart }})</p>
            </div>
            
            <product :premium="premium" @add-to-cart="updateCart"></product>    
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="prior.js"></script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change This:

```
 <button :class="{ disabledButton: !inStock }" v-on:click="add-to-cart" :disabled="!inStock">Add to Cart</button>
```

To be this:

```
 <button :class="{ disabledButton: !inStock }" v-on:click="addToCart" :disabled="!inStock">Add to Cart</button>
```

So `addToCart`: and this function will emit `add-to-cart` event

Also you can immediately run emmit onClick without adding function:

```
 <button :class="{ disabledButton: !inStock }" v-on:click="$emit('add-to-cart')" :disabled="!inStock">Add to Cart</button>
```

```js
Vue.component('product', {
    props: {
      premium: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
      }
    },
    template: `
    <div id="product">
    
      <div class="product-image">
      <img :src="image" />      
      </div>
      
      <div class="product-info">
      
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <p>Shipping: {{ shipping }}</p>
        
        <p v-if="inStock">In Stock</p>
        <p v-else>Out of Stock</p>
        
        <h2>Details</h2>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="detail in details">{{ detail }}</li>
        </ul>

        <h3>Colors:</h3>
        <div v-for="(variant,index) in variants" :key="variant.variantId">
          <div class="color-box" :style="{ backgroundColor: variant.variantColor }" @mouseover="updateProduct(index)"></div>
        </div>

        <button :class="{ disabledButton: !inStock }" v-on:click="addToCart" :disabled="!inStock">Add to Cart</button>
      </div>

    </div>
    `,
    data() {
      return {
        product: "Socks",
        brand: "Vue Mastery",
        selectedVariant: 0,
        details: ["80% cotton", "20% polyester", "Gender-neutral"],
        variants: [
            {
              variantId: 2234,
              variantQuantity: 15,
              variantColor: "green",
              variantImage: "./assets/vmSocks-green.jpg"     
            },
            {
              variantId: 2235,
              variantQuantity: 0,
              variantColor: "blue",
              variantImage: "./assets/vmSocks-blue.jpg"
            }
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addToCart() {
        this.$emit('add-to-cart')
      },
      updateProduct(index) {
        this.selectedVariant = index
      }
    },
    computed: {
      title() {
        return this.brand + ' ' + this.product
      },
      image() {
        return this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantImage
      },
      inStock() {
        if (this.variants[this.selectedVariant].variantQuantity > 0) {
          return true
        } else {
          return false
        }
      },
      shipping() {
        if (this.premium) {
          return "Free"
        } else {
          return 2.99
        }
      }
    }
  })
  
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      premium: true,
      cart: 0
    },
    methods: {
        updateCart() {
          this.cart += 1
        }
    }
  })
```

```css
body {
  font-family: tahoma;
  color:#282828;
  margin: 0px;
}

.nav-bar {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #84CF6A, #16C0B0);
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  padding: 1rem;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px .5px 1px #d8d8d8;
}

.product-image {
  width: 80%;
}

.product-image,
.product-info {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.color-box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.cart {
  margin-right: 25px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 30px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #1E95EA;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
} 

.disabledButton {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
}

.review-form {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

input {
  width: 100%;  
  height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.tab {
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.activeTab {
  color: #16C0B0;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Vue app</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav-bar"></div>

        <div id="app">
            <div class="cart">
                <p>Cart({{ cart }})</p>
            </div>
            
            <product :premium="premium" @add-to-cart="updateCart"></product>    
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="prior.js"></script>
    </body> 
</html>
```